# why error message "Operation failed after 3 times" appears even there is no re-try for error code 100

Tags: c#, json.net, task-parallel-library, polly

I want to re-try execution of code block if error code = 100 and if all re-try fails I want to print the message "Operation failed after 3 times" for this case only.

I have below Polly policy defined,

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<Exception>(ex =>
            {
                var errorMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message;
                if (errorMessage == null) return false;
                try
                {
                    dynamic error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(errorMessage);
                    if (error != null && error.errorCode == 100)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Try to run again...");
                        return true;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Error occurred: " + ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Error occurred: " + ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

And below is the code for policy execution,

```
try
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await myClass.Get());
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Operation failed after 3 times");
}
```

For below code everything perfect and I am getting desired result as well,

> Try to run again...
> Try to run again...
> Try to run again...
> Operation failed after 3 times

```
public async Task Get()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    throw new Exception("message", new Exception("{\"message\":\"inner exception\",\"errorCode\":\"100\"}"));
}
```

But when I am execution below code ( no error code = 100), then my re-try not happening but the message "Operation failed after 3 times" is also printing in console. What's the reason for it and how to avoid it?

> Exception Error occurred: message
> Operation failed after 3 times

```
public async Task Get()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    throw new Exception("message", new Exception("hey you"));
}
```

Comment: Could you provide `retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync` code please?

Comment: That you've written code that assumes the only reason it'll be handling an exception is if retries have happened is faulty. That's why it outputs "operation failed 3 times", because your code assumes that's the only reason it'll enter that `catch` clause.

Comment: This means I have to handle exception again when it's code is 100 while exexuting the code with policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me present here a solution which shows how should you solve this problem with Polly.

#### Retries vs Attempts

Let's start with clarifying some terminology.

In your code sample you have set the `retryCount` to 2 but you have 3 `Try to run again...` messages on your Console. The reason behind this is that in total you had 3 attempts: 1 initial attempt and 2 retries.

Because you have put your logging inside the `exceptionPredicate` that's why it is evaluated three times:

- After the initial attempt
- After the first retry attempt
- After the second retry attempt

The last one is bit odd since it does not trigger a retry. *Why?* Because you would exceed the retry count with that.

Later in this post we will discuss where should you put the logging.

#### The `exceptionPredicate`

Please try to keep this predicate as simple as possible. As you have seen it it is evaluated after each attempt (not after each retry)!

Rather than having a `try`-`catch` inside this predicate you can instruct the Json.Net deserializer to silently ignore errors if it can not parse the input as json.

```
var silentlyIgnoreError = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    Error = (_, args) => args.ErrorContext.Handled = true 
};
```

With this `settings` your predicate could be streamlined like this

```
.Handle<Exception>(ex =>
{
    var errorMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message;
    if (errorMessage == null) 
       return false;
    if (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(errorMessage, silentlyIgnoreError) == null) 
       return false;

    var errorCode = (string?)JObject.Parse(errorMessage)["errorCode"];
    return int.TryParse(errorCode, out int errorNumber) && errorNumber == 100;
})
```

- If the exception does not contain an inner then do not retry
- If the inner excepion's message can't be parsed as json then do not retry
- If the json does not contain an `errorCode` field then do not retry
- If the json contains an `errorCode` field but the value is not an integer then do not retry
- If the json contains an `errorCode` field with an integer value but it's different than 100 then do not retry
- Otherwise do retry :D

As you can see there is no logging here.

#### Logging

The logging logic should be placed inside the `onRetry`/`onRetryAsync` delegate which is executed when the policy has already decided that is should be triggered but before the `sleep`.

```
.WaitAndRetryAsync(2,
    _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    (ex, _, ctx) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Try to run again... ({ex.Message})");
        ctx.IncreaseRetryCount();
    });
```

- With this setup you would see only two `Try to run again...` lines

  - One after the initial attempt
  - One after the first retry attempt
- I've used a special overload of the `onRetry` which has access to the `Context`

  - It gives us ability to store information between retry attempts
  - It also allows us to access that information after the policy execution

#### The usage of `Context`

I've defined two extension methods to ease the usage of the `Context`, which is a `Dictionary<string, object>` under the hood

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    private static readonly string key = "RetryCount";

    public static void IncreaseRetryCount(this Context context)
    {
        var retryCount = GetRetryCount(context);
        context[key] = ++retryCount;    
    }

    public static int GetRetryCount(this Context context)
    {
        context.TryGetValue(key, out object count);
        return count != null ? (int)count : 0;
    }
}
```

- The `IncreaseRetryCount` is called whenever a retry will be triggered
- The `GetRetryCount` is called after the execution of the policy

#### The execution of the policy

You can execute the policy not just with the `Execute`/`ExecuteAsync` but with the `ExecuteAndCapture`/`ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` as well.

It returns a `PolicyResult`/`PolicyResult<T>` object which has the following properties:

- `Outcome`: Whether the policy/chain of policies succeeded or failed
- `FinalException`: In case of failure the final exception
- `Context`: That `Context` object which was used during the execution
- (`Result`: If the policy had been defined in a way that it should return something)

As you might expect in case of a Failure it won't throw an exception.

If you would use `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` then your code would look like this:

```
var result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () => await Get());
Console.WriteLine($"Operation has failed after the initial attempt + {result.Context.GetRetryCount()} retry attempt(s)");
```

---

For the sake of completeness here is the full source code

```
var silentlyIgnoreError = new JsonSerializerSettings { Error = (_, args) => args.ErrorContext.Handled = true };
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>(ex =>
    {
        var errorMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message;
        if (errorMessage == null) return false;
        if (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(errorMessage, silentlyIgnoreError) == null) return false;

        var errorCode = (string?)JObject.Parse(errorMessage)["errorCode"];
        return int.TryParse(errorCode, out int errorNumber) && errorNumber == 100;
    })
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(2,
        _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        (ex, _, ctx) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Try to run again... ({ex.Message})");
            ctx.IncreaseRetryCount();
        });

var result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () => await Get());
Console.WriteLine($"Operation has failed after the initial attempt + {result.Context.GetRetryCount()} retry attempts");
```

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    private static readonly string key = "RetryCount";

    public static void IncreaseRetryCount(this Context context)
    {
        var retryCount = GetRetryCount(context);
        context[key] = ++retryCount;
    }

    public static int GetRetryCount(this Context context)
    {
        context.TryGetValue(key, out object count);
        return count != null ? (int)count : 0;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**: Some correction

This piece of code:

```
var result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () => await Get());
Console.WriteLine($"Operation has failed after the initial attempt + {result.Context.GetRetryCount()} retry attempts");
```

assumed that the operation would always fail.

The correct way of handling this should be written like this:

```
var result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () => await Get());
var outcome = result.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful ? "completed" : "failed";
Console.WriteLine($"Operation has {outcome} after the initial attempt + {result.Context.GetRetryCount()} retry attempts");
```

The `OutcomeType` can be either `Successful` or `Failure`.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's not good, to have a try-catch-block in an Exception handling. In your case it's generated because of your JsonConvert, but do you really need that?

I would suggest, to throw an Exception of type [`Win32Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0), because here you can define an error code. Like this

```
throw new Exception("message", new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(100));
```

With that you don't need to do a Json-Deserialzation and you got no "second" try-catch-block.

"Operation failed after 3 times" is printed on every exception, says also on exceptions without an inner one or error code == 100. To fix that, you can now do something like

```
try
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await myClass.Get());
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    bool innerIsWin32 = ex.InnerException is System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception;
    if (innerIsWin32)
    {
        var w32ex = (Win32Exception)ex.InnerException
        if (w32ex.ErrorCode == 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation failed after 3 times");
        }
    }
}
```

Starting with C# 6, [when](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when) can be used in a catch statement to specify a condition that must be true for the handler for a specific exception to execute.

```
catch (Win32Exception ex) when (ex.InnerException is Win32Exception) {
    var w32ex = (Win32Exception)ex.InnerException;
    var code =  w32ex.ErrorCode;
    if (code == 100)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Operation failed after 3 times");
    }
}
```